# QuickLook HTML plugin?

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

I'm looking for a plugin that will display me the text of HTML files in QuickLook rather than a preview of the rendered HTML.

Does anyone know of such a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [qlcolorcode](http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/). qlcolorcode allows you to have syntax highlighting in your quicklook preview:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[qlcolorcode](http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/) didn't display HTML files by default on my installation of 10.8. I could get it to display them by adding `public.html` and `public.xhtml` to `CFBundleDocumentTypes:LSItemContentTypes` in `~/Library/QuickLook/QLColorCode.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist` and logging out and back in.

You could also remove `/System/Library/QuickLook/Web.qlgenerator/`, but it also handles `webarchive` and `svg` files. Removing the entries for `public.html` and `public.xhtml` from the `Info.plist` didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to get rid of the Web.qlgenerator to make this work, using either the QLColorCode or the QLStephen plugins, in OSX Mavericks.